# Particle Argon controlling 12V, using 3.7V LiPo

Tags: microcontroller, motor, 12v, sparkfun, step-up

I am trying to control a 12V DC motor using a Particle Argon, powered by a 3.7V LiPo. To get 12V I am using this [step up regulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016VGT6Q0), and to control the motor I am using this [DC motor controller](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14451?_ga=2.33176190.1711864056.1547661656-1156480021.1547661656). I am also using the [Particle Argon](https://docs.particle.io/argon/) as my microcontroller with a typical 3.7V LiPo battery

I am able to control the motor at a lower voltage by dropping the duty cycle at the PWM pin, but when running (particular when changing direction or starting the motor), the Particle Argon resets.

I am assuming that the current surge required when powering the motor is causing the voltage at the microcontroller to momentary drop, thus resetting it. Any thoughts? Is there a better approach to accomplish this? Maybe a capacitor anywhere is the circuit to solve this problem?

Any insight would be GREATLY appreciated.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Can you please provide links to the datasheets for the battery and the motor? These seem to be the critical components here.

Comment: Sure. The battery is a typical 3.7V 6500mAhr LiPo. Here is a link for the motor (well actuator): https://s3.amazonaws.com/actuonix/Actuonix+P16+Datasheet.pdf

Comment: No, we really need a datasheet for the battery...I don't know what "typical" means to you. The actuator datasheet is actually for several models...which one are you using, and how is it mechanically loaded?

Comment: I am using the 256:1 actuator in the data sheet. No mechanical load now, just bench testing. Here is a link to the battery https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-6500mAh-Rechargeable-Lithium-Polymer/dp/B0798DVHJ2

Comment: No, this is not a datasheet. We need something that specifies the maximum discharge rate. The vendor page does mention that this battery is not suitable for high-discharge applications, but I can't tell from what you have provided whether the battery is suitable for driving the actuator.

Comment: Ahh I see. Try this, adafruit has a download link. It's a smaller battery than the initial post, but I have one laying around. Thanks for the help! https://www.adafruit.com/product/328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your battery and step-up converter are not able to supply enough current for the motor.

To estimate how much current is needed, let's use the worst-case current required by the motor, which is the stall current of 1000mA at 12V. Depending on the load, the normal operating current looks like 100mA to 500mA, but I would expect a brief current close to the stall current when the motor starts.

So, if we need 1000mA at 12V, and we (unrealistically) expect 100% efficiency from the dc-dc converter, then you need 3000mA at 4V into the converter. This exceeds the maximum discharge current of the battery (by 3X) and also exceeds the maximum input current of the dc-dc converter (by over 2X). This is an **optimistic** estimate. It gets worse as the battery discharges and its voltage gets lower, and it gets worse if the actual efficiency of the dc-dc converter is considered.

So, bottom line, you need a much larger battery and a much more capable dc-dc converter. You might also consider using a separate battery for the actuator so the current surges don't affect the electronics.

Comment: All of that makes a lot of sense. Back to the drawing board! Thanks for breaking it down and for the help, Elliot. Very much appreciated!